# Unable to start the daemon process, incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: android-studio, gradle, daemon

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 
https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
```

How can I fix this? I don't know how to follow these instructions. This is my first time doing this. In another similar question it said to delete a file but I don't have this file in the specified location.

Answer (score 1):

Changed gradle.properties Xmx value to Xmx1024m (smaller from the original 1538 or something) and it worked!